# Load Anonymous feedback

Tags: script, javascript, voting

## Access to anonymous and low-rep post feedback

This User script allows to view anonymous and low-rep post feedback/votes under the voting menu:

[image]

You can get it from GitHub:
[Source](https://github.com/danthe1st/SO-Userscripts/blob/master/anonymous_feedback.user.js) [Install](https://github.com/danthe1st/SO-Userscripts/raw/master/anonymous_feedback.user.js)

#### What is anonymous feedback?

Stack Exchange sites allow anonymous (not logged in) and low-rep (less than the minimum cap for voting) to still "vote" on posts, even though this is not displayed.

The 10k tools allow accessing general statistics and finding outliers there but there is no option to view that feedback per question.

This information is available in the `PostFeedback` table of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

#### How does it work?

I have written [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1617807/get-count-of-anonymous-feedback-of-a-post) which loads anonymous up- and downvotes for a specific question.

The user script attempts to access `https://data.stackexchange.com/SITE_NAME/csv/1973758?postId=POST_ID` which runs the query and returns the results as a CSV table which is then processed by the user script.

#### Limitation

Due to using SEDE, the feedback is not shown instantly but (I think) only updated once per week.

#### License

It's [licensed under GPL-3.0](https://github.com/danthe1st/SO-Userscripts/blob/master/LICENSE).